# Visual Studio builds not 'updating'?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a basic winforms application and for some reason when I build the solution and run the setup, it isn't reflecting the changes I've made since the previous build? If I debug the application all my changes are there as desired.

What could be causing my builds not to reflect my changes?

Comment: What do you mean "run the setup"?

Comment: Apologies, I meant the setup created by publishing with Clickonce. I've now solved the issue, though I'm not quite sure how.